# Nav menu item moving on hover

Tags: html, css, menu

Menu text turns italic on hover, but I'm realizing that when one item becomes italic, other items move position a bit (probably b/c they want to preserve horizontal margin between them...?)

Another problem is that it's NOT italic on active state.
would appreciate help!

```
#nav a:hover {
font-style: italic;
}

#nav a:active {
font-style: italic;
}



}
.nav {
height:         58px;
margin:         0;
margin-left:    0px;
width:          100%;
```

}

```
.nav ul {
position:       absolute;
right:          0px;
height:         0px;
display:        block;
font-family:    "Adobe Garamond Pro"; 
list-style:     none;
margin:         0;
padding:        21px 40px;
color: #595959;
```

}

```
.nav li {
font-size:  19px;
float:      left;
color: #595959; 
margin-left:40px;
font-family:    "Adobe Garamond Pro";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The other items are moving because they're width are changing. Italics are smaller then regular font. If you give the .nav list items a width this should prevent them from moving around.

Also, your font-family and color are inherited properties so you don't need to define them again in your css. Instead of a float I also recommend displaying them as inline-block.

```
.nav li {
   font-size:  19px;
   margin-left:40px;
   width:75px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is I would make sure your `<a:value>` properties are in the following order:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {

}

/* visited link */
a:visited {

}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: red;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {

}
```

Source: "hover MUST come after :link and :visited (if they are present) in the CSS definition, in order to be effective!" w3schools haha